# $S$ is the set of the even numbers. Write the set implicitly and explicitly

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sorry for asking a similar question again but this one is very confusing...

I know that the set of even numbers is: $$S=\left\{0,2,4,6,8,10,12,..\right\}$$

But how you write this implicitly and explicitly?

I think what I wrote above is  explicitly?

Then implicitly would be this?:

$$S=\left\{x \in \mathbb{N_{0}}|2x=0\right\}$$

Please post a short comment or even an answer, anything would be helpful for me I'm serious!

Comment: $S=\left\{x \in \mathbb{N_{0}} \mid 2x=0\right\}$ is incorrect, as $2x = 0$ implies $x = 0$ so $S = \{0\}$.

Answer (score 3):

$S=\{x\in \mathbb N_0\mid 2x=0\}$ won't do, since for instance $2\cdot 2 \neq 0$ so $2\notin S$. In fact the only element in $S$ is 0. But you got the right idea. You could write something like
$$S = \{2n\mid n\in \mathbb N_0\}$$

Comment: +1, and by the way, $\$ \text{\mid} \$$ is preferable to $\$ | \$$ for the vertical bar; it produces, for instance, $S = \{2n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}_0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you wrote is explicit, and it looks good. You kind of have to assume that the reader understands how the pattern continues. To help understanding, you *could* write $S = \{0,2,4,6,8,10,12,\ldots,2(n-1),2n,\ldots\}$ or something, but with so simple a pattern it's not mandatory.

For implicit set notation, this is how it works:
$$
S = \{x\mid x\text{ is an element of }\Bbb N_0\text{ and fulfills certain conditions}\}
$$
or possibly
$$
S = \{x\in \Bbb N_0\mid x\text{ fulfills certain conditions}\}
$$
and it means "$S$ is the subset of $\Bbb N_0$ consisting of the elements that fulfills certain conditions". As such, $S = \{x \in \Bbb N_0 \mid x \text{ is even}\}$ is good enough for any mathematician, but for you, who are writing for some specific teacher to correct, they possibly want you to write "$x \text{ is even}$" with symbols. "$2x=0$" is not synonymous with "$x$ is even", so you have to pick something else.

Answer (score 1):

If $2x=0$, then $x=0$, so you'd just have the set $\{x\}$. By definition, a number $x$ is even if it is divisible by $2$. If that's true, how could you express that number?